# AWS DynamoDB mock always matching

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-mock

I am mocking DynamoDB query using `aws-sdk-mock`. It seems what ever query params I pass it will always match. For example looking at the implementation:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
...
const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
await dynamoDB
        .query({
            TableName: dynamoDBTableName,
            IndexName: gsiIndexName,
            KeyConditionExpression: "active = :active and reference_id = :ref_id",
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":ref_id": referenceID,
                ":active": 1,
            },
        })
        .promise()
        .then((returnData) => (data = returnData))
        .catch(console.error);
```

And my test file mocks this call like so:

```
const dynamoDBQueryParams = {
        TableName: "TABLE_NAME",
        IndexName: "INDEX_NAME",
        KeyConditionExpression: "active = :active and reference_id = :ref_id",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":ref_id": event.pathParameters.referenceDataID,
            ":active": 1,
        },
    }

AWS.mock('DynamoDB.DocumentClient', 'query', function(dynamoDBQueryParams, callback) {
   callback(null, dynamoDBExpectedReturnValues);
});
```

No matter what the `dynamoDBTableName` and `gsiIndexName` are when running the test it always will return the `dynamoDBExpectedReturnValues`. Surely if these params dont patch the mocked response should not be returned but it is. How can I assure that the matching logic is correct? Or have I implemented the mock incorrectly?

Thank you very much in advance.